# Two specific names for the properties $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $f$ be a function on a vector space including $x$ and $y$ vectors and let $c$ be a scalar. Are there two specific names for the properties $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(cx)=cf(x)$  to distinguish them from each other?

Comment: [additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) and 1-[homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

Comment: Thank you Anne Bauval. If you like you can put your answer below and I accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two properties are respectively called
[additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) and [homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) (of degree $1$).

Beware however that in the context of number theory, [additivity has another meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function).